# How to and where to use Client ID , Client Secret or Bearer Token for the Abraham\TwitterOAuth Twitter API Library?

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have used Twitter API Version 1 with Abraham\TwitterOAuth Library for posting tweets with media and ALT text. Now I want to migrate to the latest API version 2. but in the developer console, I have enabled OAuth 2.0 and I have got the Client ID and Client Secret, I am not sure whether they are required or not. and Where to use this OAuth 2.0 Client ID and Client Secret with the Abraham\TwitterOAuth.  I Have changed the end points from 'statuses/update' to the 'tweets' and I have set `$connection->setApiVersion('2');`, but still I am getting 403 error. If I `var_dump($result->errors);`, it shows "error: NULL" and `$connection->getLastHttpCode();` shows 403.
My code is below:

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>

<?php

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
  
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;
  
require_once "config.php";
require "getLastTweet.php";

$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);


 $tweet = $_POST['tweet'];
 $alt_text = $_POST['alt_text'];
 $generated_file = $_POST['generated_file'];
 $replyID = $_POST['replyID'];
 $mediaID = $_POST['mediaID'];
 $isReply = $_POST['isReply'];
 $isMedia = $_POST['isMedia'];
 
  $media = $connection->upload('media/upload', ['media' => getcwd().'/generated/'.$generated_file]); 
    
 if(($isReply==0)&& !(strlen($replyID))){
 if(strlen($tweet)>0){
//   if(strlen($media_arr)>0){
if(strlen($generated_file)>0 && $isMedia==1){
$metadata_payload = [
    'media_id' => $media->media_id_string,
    'alt_text' => [
        'text' => $alt_text,
    ],
];
$connection->post('media/metadata/create', $metadata_payload, true);


$status_payload = [
    'status' => $tweet,
    'media_ids' => $media->media_id_string,
];
$connection->setApiVersion('2');

$result = $connection->post('tweets', $status_payload,true);
// $result = $connection->post('statuses/update', $status_payload);

// removeAllFiles();
  }
  else{ 
$parameters = [
    'status' => $tweet
];
$connection->setApiVersion('2');

$result = $connection->post('tweets', $parameters,true);
// $result = $connection->post('statuses/update', $parameters);

  }

echo $connection->getLastHttpCode();
if ($connection->getLastHttpCode() == 200) {
    $tweetTime = $result->created_at;
    $id = $result->id_str;
//   echo $tweetTime;
   echo "<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'> Your Tweet Posted Successfullyy at 
   ".$tweetTime."!! You can view the tweet from <a href='https://twitter.com/i/web/status/" .$id . "'target='_blank'>here.</a></div>";

    // $_SESSION["lastTweet"] = $result->id;
    // echo '<pre>';
    $_SESSION['username']= $result->screen_name;
} else {
    echo 'error: ' . $result->errors[0]->message;
    var_dump($result->errors);
}

 }
 else{
     echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Tweet can not be empty!!!</div>';
 }
 
 }
 else{
 //Reply to last tweet
//  default to last tweet
if(strlen($replyID)){
    // No reply id set, reply to default last tweet
  if(strlen($tweet)>0){
 $twitt_reply = $tweet;
 $replyID=  getLastTweet($token,$token_secret,$consumer_key,$consumer_secret,$_SESSION['username'],1000);
//$status_id= $result->id;
if(count($media_arr)>0){
$parameters = [
    'in_reply_to_status_id'=> $replyID,
    'status' => $twitt_reply,
    'media_ids' => implode(',',$media_arr)
];
$result = $connection->post('statuses/update', $parameters);
// removeAllFiles();
}
else{
$parameters = [
    'in_reply_to_status_id'=> $replyID,
    'status' => $twitt_reply
];
$result = $connection->post('statuses/update', $parameters);

}

if ($connection->getLastHttpCode() == 200) {
    $tweetTime = $result->created_at;
    $id = $result->id_str;
//   echo $tweetTime;
   echo "<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'> Your Reply Tweet Posted Successfully at 
   ".$tweetTime."!! You can view the tweet from <a href='https://twitter.com/i/web/status/" .$id . "'target='_blank'>here.</a></div>";
} else {
    echo 'error: ' . $result->errors[0]->message;
}

  }
  else{
     '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Tweet can not be empty!!!</div>';
 }
}

  
 }
```

The code is live at: https://rahatcse5bu.com/mtwitter/

I have tried  setting `$connection->setApiVersion('2');` and resetting new endpoint for API V2 `$result = $connection->post('tweets', $parameters,true);` but  it shows 403 status Code. I want just to migrate to the V2 from V1 . My code was okay in V1. I want my code working.